# ApplicationInsights Metric Categories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I've a asp webapi.

With the ApplicationInsights library i can report custom metrics like

```
   telemetry.TrackMetric("MyMetric",1);
```

But I currently have metrics with different result categories for example:

I've

**CompanyRead**  with the results "Suceeded","NotFound","FromCache" and so on.

I want to see them together in a single Line chart to see how often which result the metric ended up over time.

What is the best way to send them to insights?

Comment: metrics are always numeric values, properties are strings.  so in your case, you'd report that property + value on whatever events you are tracking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something similar to 
Telemetry.TrackEvent(“your event name”, {CompanyRead: xxx});
And then, explore your custom telemetry by adding a new chart with your custom event name, and group them by CompanyRead

See [Create your own property](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#properties) for detail.